# Execute Task works in one area but not the other

Tags: ssis

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

I have two Execute SQL Tasks in a SSIS Package.  Each executes the same stored procedure from the SQL Statement property with a different parameter and they insert into the same table.  One is at the end of the package and only runs if a Rollback is done and it works fine.  The other runs when a script is performed that returns Failure.  When I run the other package and the Script fails the Execute SQL Task gets a green check mark but nothing is inserted into the table.

I've messed with the properties and still no luck.

I can right-click on the SQL Task choose "Execute Task" and it works as it should but of course this is not what I require.

I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Are you using the Transaction option within your SSIS package?

Comment: All the TransactionOption properties are set to "Supported".  In the Execute SQL Task I changed it "NotSupported" and got the same results.  I then changed it to "Required" and it errored.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Control Flow of your package? Also, how are you testing for a Rollback?

Comment: Someone I work with suggested using a different Connection for that task.  This worked.  I don't know why but for now it's what we're going to go with.  Thanks for your help